# Firebase получить данные пользователя по uid

Tags: java, android, firebase

У меня есть uid пользователя и нужно получить и вывести его имя и тд... Не могу найти функцию которая бы искала пользователя по его uid.

Я не создавал отдельного узла для хранения данных пользователя, ведь  firebase  и без того где-то хранит эти данные( Или умеет их находить).

Можно получить данные авторизированного пользователя

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

Мне нужно что-то такое же но что бы я мог найти пользователя по его uid.

Спасибо!

Comment: а как вы добавляете пользователей в БД?

Comment: @ Mikhail Vaysman при регистрации через гугл почту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные о пользователях хранятся отдельно от данных самой Firebase. Это сделано для безопасности. Вы можете самостоятельно сохранять эти данные в Firebase и тогда сможете их использовать. Только продумайте вопросы безопасности.